# Different ip address shown on google search

Tags: ip, google-search

I'm trying to find out my ip address and I get different answers, can someone explain me why ?

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:b6:fd:59:e7:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:4b:f5:1b:0a:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.12/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp9s0
       valid_lft 86328sec preferred_lft 86328sec
    inet6 fd48:3c0c:b6be:2600:8d59:2904:1dd4:5cdd/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 7127sec preferred_lft 3527sec
    inet6 fd48:3c0c:b6be:2600:153:e20a:3863:94e9/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7127sec preferred_lft 3527sec
    inet6 fe80::ff94:58bd:7941:f54e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Then I check it here and everything looks the same :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlYuW.png)

But when I go to google and search for "my ip", I get this answer :

"Your public IP address: 2.101.184.57"

Why do I get the answer on my laptop that my ipv4 is 192.168.1.12 and on google I get the different answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `ip a` shows your internal IP address and searching Google for "my ip" returns your external IP address as the first search result. Your external IP address (aka public IP address) will be the IP address that is used to contact your computer by the outside world. Everything connected on your side of your router is in your local network and is designated a unique internal IP address. In most cases, Internal IP addresses are issued by your router, but you may set a static IP address for the nodes in your local network. <sup>[source](https://portforward.com/networking/whatisip.htm)</sup>

The process by which several private devices connect to the internet with a single public IP address is called Network Address Translation (NAT).

Comment: Thank you Karel.

Comment: @Tomas.R it seems important to mention that this process is called Network Address Translation (NAT). More specifically it is how several private devices connect to the internet with a single public IP address. It was also created to save the internet from IPv4 address exhaustion.

Comment: @Appleoddity thank you for adding this, I might get into that later too :]